# Swift 3 - Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'NSDate' MasterViewController.swift

Tags: swift

It occurred during make example source code about iOS split view.

I want to send URL info to detailViewController so first, define variable named `siteAddresses` type `String`.

```
var siteAddresses : [String]?
```

Then input value in siteAddresses Array:

```
siteAddresses = ["www.google.com", "www.apple.com"]
```

and define function prepare for segue like

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let urlString = siteAddresses?[indexPath.row]
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailItem = urlString
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}
```

but

```
controller.detailItem = urlString
```

This part make a issue when run.

The error is:

> "Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'NSDate?'"

// edit

DetailViewController (interface) :

> internal var detailItem: NSDate? { get set }

Declared :

```
 func configureView() {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.
        if let detail = detailItem {

            if let myWebview = self.webView{
                let url = NSURL(string: detailItem as String)
                let request = NSURLRequest(URL : url!)
                myWebview.scalesPageToFit = true
                myWebview.loadRequest(request)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show how the `detailItem` property is declared.

Comment: [Edit] your question. Do not post code in comments.

Comment: ok wait a second

Comment: 1. Why are you using `NSDate` instead of `Date`? 2. Why are you trying to assign a `String` value to an `NSDate` property?

Comment: A. 1. NSDate is default value when I make a swift project select application "Master-Detail Application"
 2. I'm beginner of Swift . so I just follow example. That is just Neil Smyth's iOS programming's example

Comment: First think change data type NSDate to NSData

Comment: Well.. NSData also did not work.. OMG

Answer (score 2):

1. in prepare func

   controller.detailItem = urlString

   to

   controller.detailItem = urlString as AnyObject?
2. add in DetailViewController

   ```
    var detailItem: AnyObject? {
       didSet {
           self.configureView()
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear: You are passing a `String` where a `Date` is expected.

In Swift's strong type system the types must match.

Straightforward solution: Declare `detailItem` as `String`

```
internal var detailItem: String = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I am solving my problem

origin :

> var detailItem: NSDate? { ...

fixed :

> var detailItem: AnyObject? { ...

And

.
.
.

> controller.detailItem = urlString as AnyObject
>   .
>   .
>   .

I hope my code helps who has been suffereing for same cases.

Comment: If you know the static type of an object casting up to `AnyObject` is the worst solution.